# Post request result won't append to python DataFrame

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

#Here is the code:

```
import requests,json;
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv("vinlist.csv")
url = 'https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/vehicles/DecodeVINValuesBatch/';


for i in df['VIN']:
    if len(i) == 17:
        c=i
        post_fields = {'format': 'json', 'data':c};
        r = requests.post(url, data=post_fields);
        json_object = json.loads(r.text)
        make = json_object['Results'][0]['Make']
        model = json_object['Results'][0]['Model']
        df['make'].append(make)
        df['model'].append(model)
```

#and the error

TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'str'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest way to do what you'd like is to pass a dictionary to `.append()` with `ignore_index=True` like this:

```
to_append = {'make': json_object['Results'][0]['Make'],
             'model': json_object['Results'][0]['Model']}
df.append(to_append,ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Thanks! my first post and my first answer! Unfortunately, nothing appended to the dataframe. The columns were created, but blank.

Comment: Ah, then you might want to check that the JSON is as you're expecting it to be.